# Are there any recent advances in formalizing the undecidability of $\mathit{CH}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, continuum-hypothesis, proof-assistants, formal-proof

The website [Formalizing 100 Theorems](https://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Efreek/100/) by [Freek Wiedijk](https://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Efreek/) contains a list of some theorems that were chosen at some point as good candidates for formalization (because of their complexity, their importance, etc.) This website seems to be updated very often.

Among the proofs not yet formalized is that of the independence of the [Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) from the axioms of set theory.

> What is the current state of the formalization of the independence of $\mathit{CH}$ from $\mathit{ZFC}$?

I browsed this site for more information, and I found [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/240085/66044), as well as [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16386/66044) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/8260/66044), and an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1088656/212120) in math.SE. But I couldn't find information directly concerned with my question.

**EDIT.** We finished [our formalization](https://sanchezterraf.ar/home/forcing/) of the *countable transitive model* approach to forcing and the independence of $\mathit{CH}$. The paper is available [here](https://authors.elsevier.com/a/1ibctcCqwv-vb) and at the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.15609).

Comment: The [proof-theory] tag was suggested on this, but it seems to me that this is a little different: This one is just about _implementing_ some of the usual proofs. But I'll be glad to hear some argument supporting the tag.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205154/are-there-any-recent-advances-in-formalizing-the-undecidability-of-mathitch

Comment: This is great! But what is the exact theorem that you formalized? The countable transitive model approach to forcing, after all, does not achieve the strongest form of the result. Also, why did you choose that approach rather than the Boolean-valued model approach, which seems more direct and also more general and powerful?

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins! We (only) prove, in ZF, that given a ctm of ZFC, there exist models of ZFC+CH and ZFC+¬CH. We actually identify the always anonymous "sufficient amount of replacement" (though Matthias already knew about this).

We chose ctms because that's the first approach we understood ;-). We discuss this for the comparison to the Lean formalization. BVM are indeed more elegant.

Comment: Isn't that version of the theorem provable even in PA or much less? One doesn't need ZF in the background once one has the countable transitive model.

Comment: Of course! But that is a totally different formalization project. We would have to work essentially from scratch to do that. Here we could reuse some material on relativization already available using ZF.


Motivated by this, I asked about proof assistants with the ability to work with different metatheories [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/425/428), but I guess there is not much support on that yet.

Comment: (There are actually a bit stronger versions which talk about ctms of fragments of ZFC, but anyone interested can check that on the paper.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jesse Michael Han and Floris van Doorn recently formalized the independence of the continuum hypothesis in the [Lean theorem prover](https://leanprover.github.io). See [the Flypitch project webpage](https://flypitch.github.io/about/) for their papers and code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of their results. Actually, this surprised us in the middle of our development of the ctm approach to forcing in Isabelle/ZF (for instance see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03313)). We'll soon upload some new material on that.